# React native Image: fit width and bottom overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add and image into a View (represented by the black square on the example bellow), the view size depends on screens sizes. I also want an `overflow: hidden` on the bottom of my image if the first view is to small

[image]

If I try on my image :

```js
    width: '100%',
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 1,
```

my image is centered, and not anchor to the top.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap image in a div and define the size of div in css and a overflow:hidden property to that div.

```
.myBlackBox{
        width: 500px;
        border: 5px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

My div css properties.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem don't come from the container, but from the image which it don't have a good respect ratio + anchor to the top

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cont {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <img width="100%" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/93/Burj_Khalifa.jpg/1200px-Burj_Khalifa.jpg" />
</div>

<hr>

<img width="200px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/93/Burj_Khalifa.jpg/1200px-Burj_Khalifa.jpg" />
```